# What is the best way of introducing set theory?

Tags: discrete-math, set-theory

The students are aware of mathematical logic and proof but have not come across any of the notions of a set. What is the most natural and motivating way to introduce set theory?

Comment: I think it would help potential answerers to answer your question  if you expanded your question to describe the class in which "the students" you refer to are currently enrolled. (A)  If you are teaching a discrete math or discrete structures course and you need to include a brief introduction to introductory set theory, there are a few great texts; (B) however, if your "the students" are enrolled in a semester's course in introductory set theory, there are other texts that best serve this purpose.  But the intersection of recommended texts for (A) and (B) do not intersect.

Comment: Also, it seems to me that your students might be aware of propositional and predicate logic, and have some experience doing proofs.  If they studied *mathematical* logic, they would have invariably covered introductory set theory in the said course.  E.g., the text ["A mathematical introduction to Logic"](http://agnigarh.tezu.ernet.in/~zubin/isc/extra/MathematicalIntroductionToLogic-Enderton.pdf) by H. Enderton devotes chapter 0 to basics about sets.

Comment: What aspect are you worrying about? If they somehow already know logic and proofs, why not just get on with it? Is there some particular point you expect them to have problems with?

Comment: This is part of the introductory to number theory. I would ideally like to connect this to logic and proof rather than a set of isolated rules. I am looking for a narrative.

Comment: This is extremely vague and overly broad.

Comment: Are the students bachelor students at a university or something else?

Comment: Yes first year undergraduate students.

Comment: @matqkks And the first year students are taking a class from you called "Introductory to number theory?" Probably not. Which class are they taking from you?

Comment: *This is part of the introductory to number theory. I would ideally like to connect this to logic and proof rather than a set of isolated rules.* --- Ivan Niven's [**Numbers: Rational and Irrational**](http://users.auth.gr/siskakis/Niven-NumbersRationalAndIrrational.pdf) has a lot of discussions of basic applied logic (see pp. 19, 26-30) that might be helpful, but not really anything all that specific about sets. To what extent do your students need to know about sets besides the basic notions of union, intersection, etc. that appear at the beginning of most every undergraduate level text?

Comment: Numbers and sets but I find they have forgotten all the work they did in this module so I trying to provide a brief introduction to logic, proof and sets for the start of the number theory module which they take in their second year (sophomore) as undergraduates

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The student background in proofs and logic is not necessary for initial explanation/motivation of the concepts.  And actually it worries me that you mention that when wanting to know how to do an initial introduction!  I remember learning the basics of sets (and union, intersection, etc.) as an elementary schoolkid in the New Math.  You do not need a huge background to start looking at the topic.  This is very different from calculus where you really do need some background in algebra, functions, analytic geometry, etc.

The easiest way to first explain the concept is as a collection of things (e.g. stamps, books, etc.) see pages 5-6 of Tenenbaum Ordinary Differential Equations.

Of course you should move to generalize to infinite sets and more difficult concepts.  And the students have background to handle that.  But to START, just do exercises with  simple sets of integers.  E.g.  (1, 3, 5, 7, 9) versus (2, 4, 6, 8, 10) versus (3, 7, 11, 214) versus (3, 5, 7, 1, 9).  I recommend using integer collections as the starting point as it is easy to look at them and discuss union/intersection.  Of course, you can move to more fancy complicated things.  But start simple.

You can illustrate with Venn diagrams also.

Of course, given the level of the students you can move to some formal proofs as well.  AFTER they have been introduced to the topic.  but I would not START any topic with a definition, theorem, proof, example style of teaching.

P.s.  I also suggest looking at some books (hard and easy) for their approaches.  This should not just be something to be solved de novo by a question here.  [Or with an approach of constructing a course from scratch.  Anyone who DOES construct a course from scratch should have some deep perspective before doing so...and I don't mean deep math perspective.  I mean in addition to that having seen different pedagogical approaches and having some formed ideas on what works/doesn't.]